# Hide labels in googleVis Bubble Charts

Tags: json, r, google-visualization, googlevis

I want to hide the labels. I believe it is something to do with the option `bubble.textStyle` and setting the color to `none` but I can't figure it out.

```
Bubble <- gvisBubbleChart(Fruits, idvar="Fruit", xvar="Sales", yvar="Expenses",
                          colorvar="Year", sizevar="Profit",
                          options=list(hAxis='{minValue:75, maxValue:125}',
                                       width=500, height=300))
plot(Bubble)
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tricky thing is that it's a JSON object inside a JSON object. First you use `bubble="{}` to create the first JSON object and then `textStyle:{}` to create the next JSON object inside  `bubble="{}`.

Here is my code and a screenshot,

```
# install.packages("googleVis", dependencies = TRUE)
require(googleVis)

Bubble <- gvisBubbleChart(Fruits, idvar="Fruit", xvar="Sales", yvar="Expenses",
                          colorvar="Year", sizevar="Profit",
                          options=list(hAxis='{minValue:75, maxValue:125}',
                                       width=500, height=300),
                                       bubble="{textStyle:{color: 'none', fontName: 
                                       <global-font-name>, fontSize: 
                                       <global-font-size>}}")
plot(Bubble)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Eric! It works a treat now!  `Bubble <- gvisBubbleChart(Fruits, idvar="Fruit", xvar="Sales", yvar="Expenses",
                          colorvar="Year", sizevar="Profit",
                          options=list(hAxis='{minValue:75, maxValue:125}',
                                       width=500, height=300,
                          bubble="{textStyle:{color: 'none'}}"));
plot(Bubble);`